# how to identify the orientation of viewController's subclass in ipad

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios5, xcode4.2

I have one viewController class example FirstView and it has one subclass ex. secondView.
SecondView is a subclass of FirstView.Now I want to check the orientation in second view?

How to identify the secondView orientation?I checked the following method but its not working.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

When I change the orientation no method is called.

Is there any way to identify the orientation of the custom subclass?

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]` returns you the current device orientation.

Comment: I got the current device in viewDidLoad but i how do i identify the orientation when i change the orientation?which method is called when i change the orientation?

Comment: `- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration` is called before rotation and `- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation` is called after one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use UIAccelerometer. You just need to implement the UIAccelerometerDelegate.

Just to get the current orientation of the view using Accelerometer you can use this code:

```
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration
{
    // Get the current device angle
    float x = [acceleration x];
    float y = [acceleration y];
    float angle = atan2(y, x); 



 if([acceleration z]>-0.84)
 {
        if(angle >= -2.25 && angle <= -1)  // Current Orientation = Portrait
        {
             //Do the work
        } 
        else if(angle >= -0.35 && angle < 0.20) //Current Orientation = Landscape Left
        {
              //Do the work
        }
        else if(angle >= 0.90 && angle <= 2.00) //Current Orientation = Portrait Upside Down
        {
             //Do the work
        }
        else if(angle <= -2.70 || angle >= 2.5) //Current Orientation = Landscape Right
        {
              //Do the work
        }
   }
}
```

Let me know if you need more help on this.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In you super class you should call the orientation method of its super like:

```
Class A {
    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
         [super shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation];
    }
}

class b inherits class a {
    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
     NSLog(@"Your stufs");    
    }
}
```